# Exporting to S-57 basefile using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, s-57

I want to export layers in QGIS as a S-57 basefile, but can't get it to work.

Is there any documentation available regarding the processing parameters?

I get error message when i try to export, regardless of geometry type.
Example:

```
 Export to vector file failed.
 Error: Creation of layer failed (OGR error: CreateLayer() not 
 supported by this dataset.)
```

I mainly want to know where I can find more documentation about the workings of this export feature.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "create" support for S-57 in OGR (the library QGIS depends upon), see https://www.gdal.org/ogr_formats.html:

```
Format Name | Code | Creation | Georeferencing | Compiled by default
S-57 (ENC)  | S57  | No       | Yes            | Yes
```

Comment: Ok that’s a clear answer, but why is it possible then in QGIS to export to S-57 basefile? Does it use different lib’s?

Comment: @CaptainAhab, based on your question and this answer, apparently it's *not* possible to export to S-57 basefile format in QGIS. "S-57 basefile" does appear as an export option, but it seems like that's a mistake. I suggest making an [error report](https://issues.qgis.org).

Comment: @csk i’m not yet convinced this is an error. The export menu for S-57 basefile, for me, is too elaborate to be a mistake, it also contains specific S-57 features..

Comment: "Preliminary S-57 export capability has been added in GDAL/OGR 1.2.0 but is intended only for specialized use, and is not properly documented at this time." source: https://www.gdal.org/drv_s57.html